# Java: write multiple input streams to a single file and read input streams back from file

Tags: java, file, io, blob

I am reading the `Blob` instance as an `input stream` from the `database` and writing that each individual `input stream` into a single separate `File` at the local filesystem. This results in about the millions of var-binary files are being created, so I would like to create a single `File` for each and every `Blob` instance rather than creating an individual file for each `Blob` instance. I will also restore these `Blob` instance back into the database.

I also find an option to create a single tar file and add each `Blob` instance as a stream to tar file but then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770492/how-do-i-append-files-to-a-tar-archive-in-java), which says-

> It has a limitation and because of that, it is hard to add or remove
>   single files without copying the whole archive.

**So I wonder if it would be possible that I can write all `Blob` instance into a single file and read them back correctly from that single file?**

**Please suggest me how can I achieve this?**

**Will `RandomAccessFile` help me in this strategy because it has file pointer?**

Comment: Do the blobs have always the same length? Than RandomAccessFile would be enough since you don't need to handle a journal of all entries, you can determine the exact position via size*position

Comment: Another suggestion: With classes from the JDK you could also use ZipIn- and ZipOutputstream, but you can't append/remove files once it's closed (like with tar files). Though there are some external libraries you could look into, like TrueZip.

Comment: @matt they would be of different length. Would it be possible to keep track of start and end offset of each `Blob` instance if they are not of the same size and read back with the help of those start and end offset? Assuming if start and end offset against each `Blob` instance are being saved into another file.

Comment: Well yes, but you would need to keep track of this on your own in some way - and this would also need to be persisted I guess?

Comment: @matt Thank you. Will try and get back to you. Thank a lot.